# Is there a decent, standalone, cross-platform webserver that will work in concert with Autorun on USB Jump Drives?

Tags: cross-platform, webserver

I'm trying to find a decent standalone webserver that I can load up on a jump drive.

My wife is a photographer, and I'd like to present the clients with their images on usb. When they plug it in, I'd like a web page to load up, and run some jQuery magic to show them a nice carousel of all there images.

So far, this is all fine since it can all be done client side and doesn't need a server at all.

The problem I'm facing is that I'd like some server-side code to be able to read the images out of the directory so that once the interface is built, I don't need to manually create all of the `<img />` tags.

If it was primarily going to be used in a Windows environment, I'd have no problem going with IIS Express, since I'm mainly a .NET MVC developer and this would be perfect for me... However, the fact of the matter is that a large amount of our client base is also OS X users.

I did find this Java one [jlHttp](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jlhttp/), and I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499084/minimal-standalone-distributable-cross-platform-web-server) here on SO, but I don't think I understand enough about either one of them to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same thing, and the two best options I've found were [Flying Ant](http://www.wrensoft.com/flyingant/index.html) cd web server and [Stunnix](http://www.stunnix.com/prod/aws/overview.shtml).   Of the two, Flying Ant is cheaper, and I've tested it with success on my project.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) very convenient for this exact purpose.  It's crossplatform, lightweight and requires minimum configuration. You may be interested in [this project](https://github.com/dredix/dsgallery) that uses Mongoose to display pictures in a folder tree or FTP directory.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

It says it runs on Linux, OS X, and Windows.